# show() and toggle() not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

`b1` hides the image while `b2` doesn't show it. Also the `toggle` function does not work? What is wrong in my code?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".b1").click(function() {
    $("img").hide();
  });

  $(".b2").click(function() {
    $("img").show();
  });     
});
```

Comment: could you check if `$(".b2").click` is fired or not?

Comment: Without HTML this code is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it is impossible to give the right answer . If I assume that everything is good with the HTML and CSS , I would do something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var imgOne = $(".b1");
var imageTwo = $(".b2");

var imgClass = $(".img-class");


  imgOne.on("click",function() {
    imgClass.hide();
  });

  imageTwo.on("click",function() {
    imgClass.show();
  });     
});
```

You can also add `console.log('pass')` when you click to see if the functions are even doing something . Like this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var imgOne = $(".b1");
var imageTwo = $(".b2");

var imgClass = $(".img-class");


  imgOne.on("click",function() {
    console.log('pass hide');
    imgClass.hide();
  });

  imageTwo.on("click",function() {
    console.log('pass show');
    imgClass.show();
  });     
});
```

You should see these prints in the console if everything works ok . 
Try it out . Hope this helps :)